# Can vs Will be able to

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, indian-english

I ran across a ques­tion in a gram­mar test that was ask­ing for a 
par­tic­u­lar sen­tence, and sup­pos­edly the re­quired an­swer is
the first sen­tence given be­low, but **not** the sec­ond one,
which they’re call­ing wrong:

1. If I read this book, I will be able to get a lot of knowl­edge.
2. If I read this book, I can get a lot of knowl­edge.

Aren’t both of those right? Don’t they mean the same thing? What’s 
“wrong” with the sec­ond ver­sion? What is the dif­fer­ence be­tween
*can* and *will be able to* in those two par­tic­u­lar sen­tences?
Are both right?

Note that I do **not** want to learn the dif­fer­ence be­tween *can* and
*be able to* in a gen­eral way, be­cause I’m pretty sure I al­ready know
that. My prob­lem is that I find the al­leged ex­pla­na­tion for why only
sen­tence one not sen­tence two is the cor­rect an­swer to be ut­terly
un­sat­is­fy­ing:

> Can I def­i­nitely get a lot of knowl­edge? No. The con­di­tion 
>   that leads to get­ting a lot of knowl­edge is read­ing this book,
>   but I might not read this book.

I don’t un­der­stand.

Comment: If you read this on a test, my suggestion is find another teacher that has a better understanding of English usage. i.e."...get a lot of knowledge"??

Comment: That explanation only really applies to the use of the comma. If something is certain, regardless of the condition that follows, then no comma should be used. At least in one interpretation. *I will eat my breakfast, if it pleases you* versus *I will eat my breakfast if it pleases you*. The version with the comma says that you liking it is incidental; the version without the comma says that you liking it is necessary. But not all people follow that. There is no difference between the two sentences, and the explanation, if it's valid in any sense, doesn't apply to only one version.

Answer (score 1):

"Can" is possible in this case. But it will mean "will possibly get some knowledge" instead of "being able to get some knowledge"

Compare these:

If I study hard, I can make lots of money=If I study hard, I will possibly make lots of money.

If I study hard, I will be able to speak four languages=If I study hard, I will gain the ability to speak four languages.

Comment: Why can't it mean "being able to get some knowledge" with "can"?

Comment: "will be able to" usually means that a general ability is gained after something is done. 

If I practice more, I can play piano (??? Doesn't make sense. It sounds if "you will play piano" instead of "gain the ability to play the piano) 

If I practice more, I will be able to play the piano (the ability to play the piano is gained after you practice more. The ability doesn't apply to only one occasion but will preserve after the condition is fulfilled)

Comment: Also, for type 2 conditionals, among the effects of the modal "can" (suggestions, permission, ability, and possibility) only the meaning of possibility remains. While for type 1, the modal "can" still has effects other than the possibility. For example, "If you ask politely, you can go to the toilet (permission)" or "If you want to, we can take a bus (suggestion)

Comment: However, if it's talking about a general ability that is gained after the fulfillment of the condition, neither type 1 or 2 accepts "can" in the main clause.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. You make claims in your first and third comments without citing any authority, such as a grammar book. The claim in the first comment seems to be easily disproven by a sentence such as "if you try hard enough, then you can do whatever you want", which I believe means the same as "if you try hard enough, then you will be able to do whatever you want".

Comment: In your case,
 "If you try hard enough, then you can do whatever you want"=> doing whatever you want will be possible. 

"If you change your outfit quickly, we can get on the stage in time"=> getting on the stage in time will be possible.

And yes, changing the second part into "will be able to" works as well. But it will be a one-time successful event instead of a general ability.

Comment: If I train hard enough, I will be able to run very fast. (O)=> You gain the general ability to run very fast. 
If I train hard enough, I can run very fast (X)=> Doesn't sound right, but it can be claimed that that I run very fast becomes something possible.

Comment: If you help me out, I can solve this problem very quickly=> Solving this problem quickly will be possible. 
If you help me, I will be able to solve this problem very quickly.=> I will gain the ability to solve this problem. 

If you give me more money, I can buy this car. => buying this car will be possible
If you give me money, I will be able to buy this car. =>I will gain the ability to buy this car

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not convinced. In any case, I think that your answer would be much stronger if you explained what you meant more clearly (I don't think that the points that you're making about "general ability", "one-time successful event", etc. are obvious to most people) and if you cited some kind of source to support your claim.

Comment: Just look at this sentence: If I study hard, I can speak Chinese. It doesn’t look right, right?

Comment: https://languagetool.org/insights/post/can-could-grammar/ 

This is a good source that you might want to see (using "can" to mean possibility).

Comment: Whether I understand your argument isn't really important; my point is that I think that your answer should include more detail and explanation.